# Variable scope of function without parameter input

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope

I am trying to understand the variable scope in Python (3.x), but below is an example of code that does not work and I am not sure why.

```
def function_a(A):
    function_b()

def function_b():
    print(A)

function_a(1)
```

Which results in `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`

So, the way I would think it works is that `function_a()` and `function_b()` are definid. Afterwards I run `function_a()` where `A` gets assigned the value of 1.

So in the scope of `function_a()` the variable A=1 exists.

Then `function_b()` gets called and is meant to print the value of variable `A`. A does not exist in the scope of function_b(). Hence I would expect it to look a level higher, which would be the scope of `function_a()` because `function_b()` is run within `function_a()`.

But clearly, I am getting that wrong. What actually happens?

Comment: While it's not _directly_ relevant to this question, I suspect that you may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you have called `function_b` inside of `function_a` doesn't mean it would inherit the scope of `function_a` and for good reasons. The function gets the scope from where it's defined, not where it's called.

If you want to accomplish something like `closures` you should try to define `function_b` inside of `function_a`.

```
def function_a(A):
     def function_b():
         print(A)
```

With that said, I don't really see a use case for a closure here. You're better off passing the variable as an argument. That way it would be more reusable and testable.

```
def function_a(A):
    function_b(A)

def function_b(A):
    print(A)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Hence I would expect it to look a level higher, which would be the
>   scope of `function_a()` because `function_b()` is run within
>   `function_a()`

It does look higher. But the scope of `function_a` is not higher than that of `function_b`. The scopes are somewhat independent. Don't confuse scoping hierarchies with stack frames. The next scope in the hierarchy is the module scope, which here, is the global scope; `A` is not in the global scope.

To access `A` in `function_b`, you can pass it as a parameter to `function_b` or define `A` in the module scope.

Comment: Upvoted, but I think you should consider wording it in a way that's easier for newbies to understand - IMO there's a bit too much technical lingo ("scoping hierarchies", "stack frames") here, when you could've expressed the same thing in a much clearer way by saying something like "the function's scope depends on where it was _defined_, not where it was _called_".

Comment: @Rawing Thanks for the feedback. I guess that's what the accepted answer did, and most probably why it got accepted. Learning...

Comment: As the one who has asked the question I can confirm that it was indeed the reason why I accepted @hspandher 's answer. I also upvoted your answer though because it did indeed answer the question. I just thought the other answer made it a bit clearer by saying 'The function gets the scope from where it's defined, not where it's called.'

Thanks for your answer though

Answer (score 1):

What happens is, in `function_b`, a search in the global scope is done and since the global scope doesn't define a name `A` and no enclosing function scope exists, you get a `NameError`.

If an enclosing scope existed:

```
def function_a(A):
    def function_b():
        print(A)
    function_b()
function_a(1)  # prints 1
```

Or a global name `A` was defined:

```
A = 2
def function_a(A):
    function_b()

def function_b():
    print(A)

function_a(1)  # prints 2 (finds global name A)
```

you'd get the result of `A` printed since the look-up would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this occurs because python does not place the bindings to parameters in the same namespace that a variable binding receives. The parameter bindings exist only within the function's scope.

The proper way to achieve your effect is using python closures (which enclose their parent function's namespace):

```
def function_a(A):
    def function_b():
        print(A)

    function_b()

function_a(1)
```

You may simply pass the value `A` to both functions, but this may suggest that you should make a class containing `A` (especially if `A` is required by many functions):

```
class A(object):
    def __init___(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def function_a(self):
        self.function_b()

    def function_b(self):
        print(self.a)

 foo = A(1)
 foo.function_a()
```